# Gitlab branding customisation

Tags: gitlab

I have installed gitlab CE on my linux server. it is running well, now i want to change branding of gitlab and want to put my logo and favicon, also want to change the name "gitlab"

is this possible? if yes, let me know  how I can do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming.

Comment: Ask Gitlab developers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is now possible in the community edition. Simply head to:

http://your-git-url/admin/appearance

Comment: Thank you Frap, it is working. could you please let me know, how could I change favicon? there is no option for favicon change.

Comment: This is not currently possible: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15661

Comment: If my answer helped you, please ensure to click the tick and upvote :)

Comment: Thank you once again. I have successfully changed the Gitlab favicon.