# how to change the favicon( logo) in gitlab manually

Tags: gitlab

I installed Gitlab community version - 10.8.2 on ubuntu. Now I am trying to change the favicon for that git lab's appearance. But I don't have the option in **Admin ->appearance** , Would you please suggest Is there any way to change that favicon in git-lab. Thanks ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YENTj.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gitlab branding customisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693612/gitlab-branding-customisation)

Comment: And, you asked same question for two times which is previously a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we got 11.0.0 update in both Gitlab-ce and Gitlab-ee, favicon is easy to change in `Appearance`  in `Admin area`.

Comment: Thanks @Rajana Deepak for giving the information.  Definitely  i will try that once.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rajana Deepak. Now it is working fine. favicon was updated successfully.

Comment: If it is working, accpet the answer. So that other users can get benifitted

Answer (score 1):

There is no option currently to set custom favicon as mentioned in this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15661).

And this question is already answerd in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693612/gitlab-branding-customisation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thank you Rajana Deepak , I don't have favicon change(uploader)  option admin->appearance in my Gitlab. Cloud you please suggest me to change the favicon? i followed the following link - https://www.tienle.com/2015/03-31/change-gitlab-branding-logo-and-favicon.html. I am facing pre compilation errors.

Comment: In [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15661) issue of Gitlab-ce, it is clear that, favicon change option is not availble till now. The CEO of `Gitlab` commentend on the issue that "_I'm not a fan of this proposal, favicon should match our logo in the top left, in the future we might use the favicon to indicate the user has messages. /cc_" . The method you followed is not ethical way. It may lead to errors.